# Remove specific records from associative array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, null, associations

Hi I have an array that contains two arrays that has the following structure:

```
categories [
  "lvl0" => array:2 [
    0 => "Cleaning"
    1 => "Bread"
  ]
  "lvl1" => array:2 [
    0 => null
    1 => "Bread > rolls"
  ]
]
```

I would like to remove any records of NULL from the 'lvl1' array but have not been able to find the correct method to do this.

I have tried:

```
array_filter($categories['lvl1'])
```

But this also removes all records associated to lvl1 and not just the NULL ones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `array_combine(array_keys($categories),array_map('array_filter',$categories))`

Comment: `$categories['lvl1'] = array_filter($categories['lvl1'])`?

Comment: Can you add a bit more code to show the context in which you used `array_filter($categories['lvl1'])`? _That should not remove any non-empty values._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robbie Averill who commented on my post with the following solved the issue:

```
$categories['lvl1'] = array_filter($categories['lvl1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` takes a callback as the second argument. If you don't provide it, it returns only records that aren't equal to boolean `false`. You can provide a simple callback that removes empty values.

`array_filter()` also uses a copy of your array (rather than a reference), so you need to use the return value.

For instance:

```
$categories = [
  "lvl0" => [
    "Cleaning",
    "Bread"
  ],
  "lvl1" => [
    null,
    "Bread > rolls"
  ]
];

$lvl1 = array_filter($categories['lvl1'], function($value) {
    return !empty($value);
});

var_dump($lvl1);
```

That will return:

```
array(1) {
  [1] =>
  string(13) "Bread > rolls"
}
```

Comment: Using `return !empty($value);` in the callback actually has the same effect as not using a callback.

Comment: Technically, sure. But it's also less instructive because it doesn't show him how to make changes to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my last working day.Generally for associative array `array_filter()` needs the array key to filter out `null`, `false` etc values. But this small function help me to filter out `NULL` values without knowing the associative array key. Hope this will also help you, https://eval.in/881229

**Code:**

```
function array_filter_recursive($input)
  {
    foreach ($input as &$value)
    {
      if (is_array($value))
      {
        $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
      }
    }

    return array_filter($input);
  } 

$categories = [
  "lvl0" => [
    "Cleaning",
    "Bread"
  ],
  "lvl1" => [
    null,
    "Bread > rolls"
  ]
];

$result = array_filter_recursive($categories);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
(
    [lvl0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cleaning
            [1] => Bread
        )

    [lvl1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Bread > rolls
        )

)
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87581